# What is the correct way to write a response body in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using the following function to make a POST request in kotlin.

```
fun makeRequest(url: String, body: String): String{
        var builder = StringBuilder()
        val connection = URL(url).openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
        connection.setDoOutput(true)
        connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0)
        connection.requestMethod = "POST"
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")

        val jsonbody = Gson().toJson(body)
        val wr = OutputStreamWriter(connection.outputStream, "utf-8")
        wr.write(jsonbody)
        wr.flush()

        try{
            var data: Int = connection.inputStream.read()
            while (data != -1) {
                builder.append(data.toChar())
                data = connection.inputStream.read()
            }
        }catch(e: Exception){
            builder = StringBuilder()
            builder.append(connection.responseMessage)
        }finally {
            wr.close()
            connection.disconnect()
        }
        return builder.toString()
    }
```

and inside my fragment, I have a button onClickListener as follows:

```
signInButton.setOnClickListener {
                val acc = userAccountTextField.text.toString()
                val pw = userPasswordTextField.text.toString()

                val body = """{"username":$acc,"password":$pw}"""
                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch{
                    val output = makeRequest( getString(R.string.url)+"user/login" , body)
                    Snackbar.make( view , output, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
```

I am able to make request to my localhost, however, it does not detect request body and returns 400 error. What is the proper way to write a response body? Is the issue with the string i pass to the method, or the outputstreamwriter?

I also found this error on my sailsjs project, so I am assuming that theres something wrong with the way I am writing the json?

```
error: Unable to parse HTTP body- error occurred :: 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0\n' +
  '    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)\n' +
  '    at createStrictSyntaxError
```

[ngrok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpSxR.png)

Comment: Why didnt you use retrofit?

Comment: @miladsalimi its part of an assignment. I was provided a previous GET method which uses the httpurlConnection, so I am assuming that I wouldnt need to use extra packages